Access command line arguments passed to "pnpm run" in package.json
I need to pass command line arguments to the pnpm run command and access them via the scripts in package.json file.
For example, I would run the pnpm command like below.
pnpm run create:migration -- --name=RoleMigration

I need to access the argument passed to name like below in package.json.
"scripts": {
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "create:migration": "typeorm migration:create ./src/migrations/$pnpm_config_name",
}

This article mentions that you could usually access those arguments in npm via $npm_config_{my_argument}. Therefore, I was trying to do a similar thing for pnpm using $pnpm_config_{my_argument} which apparently does not work.
https://dev.to/amirfakour/using-typeorm-migration-in-nestjs-with-postgres-database-3c75
It will execute the following command in the shell and does not replace the variables.
pnpm run create:migration -- --name=RoleMigration

 > typeorm migration:create ./src/migrations/$pnpm_config_name "--" "--name=RoleMigration"

Does anybody know a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Sadly, pnpm doesn't support accessing args directly using $pnpm_config_{arg} like npm does, but you can try using enviroment variables or a custom script to pass the args and create enviroment variables.
//create-env.js
process.argv.slice(2).forEach(arg => {
    const [key, value] = arg.split("=");
    if (value && key) {
        process.env[key] = value;
    }
});
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const child = spawn("pnpm", ["run", process.argv[2], ...(process.argv.slice(3))], {stdio: "inherit", env: process.env});
child.on("close", code => {
    process.exit(code);
});

I hope this idea works for you. Good luck. If you find that you can't, you might just have to use npm.
EDIT:
new package.json:
{
    "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "create:migration": "node set-env.js create:migration --name=$name"
    }
}

you will have to use:
pnpm run create:migration -- --name=RoleMigration

to run it with pnpm.

Thanks for the answer. But this is not what I was looking for.
